# Spring Cloud Config - Dynamic property

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

When centralized cloud config server runs, I need to send a dynamic property (secret.key - which is randomly generated) to all its subscribed services. Like a secret key.

With cloud config, I can get properties defined in properties file. For this situation, how it can be exposed by config server?

Comment: Where is the randomly generated property defined?

Comment: In cloud config server, it has to be generated and propagated to services, which subscribed to cloud config server. One way is to use Netflix Archaius with ZooKeeper. I would like to know how it is possible with Cloud Config.

Comment: So you want the property to be pushed to config clients so they know about the property?

Comment: yes. How it can be done without zookeeper?

Comment: Have you tried using the `monitor` endpoint? http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Camden.SR5/#_push_notifications_and_spring_cloud_bus

Comment: Try spring cloud bus. check this out with one url you can refresh the properties for all the services or just the ones you want. https://spencer.gibb.us/blog/2015/09/24/spring-cloud-config-push-notifications/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try the Spring Cloud Bus